# is there any way to off click on ajax loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having click events in jquery like

```
$("#elementId").off("click").on("click",function (event) {
    // some code
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

In this case i am using `off` and then `on` click. And here is another way in case of ajax loaded element.

```
    $(document).on("click", "#elementId",function (event) {
         //some code 
        $(this).unbind( "click" );
       });
```

I just came to know that

1.
is there any way to `off` click along with `on` click as in first case.However second one is also working fine.

2.What is difference between both approach.`$("#elementId").off("click").on("click",function (event)` and `$(this).unbind( "click" );` inside click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.off()` can be written in the following manner -

```
$( "body" ).off( "click", "p", foo );
```

This answers your first question. So you could do something like this,

```
$(document).off('click', '#elementId').on('click', '#elementId',function (event) {
   //some code 
   $(this).unbind( 'click' );
});
```

Please read more about it in the documentation - http://api.jquery.com/off/#off-events-selector

To answer your second question, the first piece of code will remove any existing event handlers and then attach new handlers. The second piece of code will let the event handler trigger only once.

Also instead of using `.unbind`, I'd suggest you use `.off` itself since `.unbind` is deprecated. See here - http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Demo for your second question here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmgbQM